# Python 2.7.5 installation crashes on Windows XP 32-bit

Tags: windows-xp, installation, python

Like on a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16846336), I have similar problem. I want to try a python framework for Wikibot, but need to run Python on Windows, which is not in default OS installation. Downloaded version 2.5.7 and ran it, but after proceeding an error occured and install crashed. Using Windows XP Service Pack 3 32-bit... I tried to redownload pack, looked for the encryption checkbox having unchecked -> true, no success. Does Python support Windows XP? What I'm doing wrong?

---

Note: transfered from [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17834323)

Comment: Make sure that you have XP SP3 (Atleast XP SP2)

Comment: Also check the event log for any errors related to the installation

Comment: @GaneshR. Using Windows XP Service Pack 3 32-bit...
Where I find event log, of course?

Comment: in run prompt, type eventvwr.msc. It should open the event log.

Comment: @GaneshR. Error address `0x00025eaa`. Error text: _"Application Failure  msiexec.exe 4.5.6001.22159 in msihnd.dll 3.1.4001.5512 at offset 00025eaa"_ What's wrong?

Comment: Looks like the problem is overall global. Error has occured directly in execution program, not installer package. Tried with another msi installation -> the same result: crash. Looks like something went wrong in the `msihnd.dll` module... Where can I download a patch to fix it? Do I need to wait for Windows Update? I read a support for Windows XP will definitely quit...

Comment: Problem solved, had to download hotfix...

Comment: Great. Add the link to the hotfix and explain what you had to do as an answer. Accept it after 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I found the [solution](http://thebackroomtech.com/2010/09/14/repair-windows-installer-errors/):

> ### Method 2 – Reinstall Windows Installer
>
> You can also try to repair the problem by reinstalling Windows Installer! Pretty ironic eh! The first thing we want to do is rename some of the current windows installer files before we download the new ones.
>
> Click on Start, Run and type in cmd. Then type in the following commands below. Press Enter after each command.
>
> > cd %windir%\system32
> >     attrib -r -s -h dllcache
> >     ren msi.dll msi.old
> >     ren msiexec.exe msiexec.old
> >     ren msihnd.dll msihnd.old
>
> Next, you want to download the latest version of Windows Installer. We can do that from the Microsoft Download Center.
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/default.aspx
>
> Type in Windows Installer in the search box and find the latest version, which will be called Windows Installer X.X Redistributable. Once installed, restart your computer.

By this *answer* I would suggest to close the question as solved.